# VSC SFML terminated with exit code: 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, mingw, sfml

I have this error when I compil a c++ code with SFML in Visual Studio Code :

```
` The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command ../mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -v -g src/*.cpp -o bin/main.exe -DDEBUG -I../lib/SFML/include -L../lib/SFML/lib -lmingw32 -lstdc++ -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. `
```

Here is my lauch.json :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "GCC build and debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            //Pay attention to change to your own MinGW directory
            "miDebuggerPath": "../mingw64//bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "Build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here my tasks.json :

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "GCC_Debug",
            "command": "../mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-v",
                "-g",
                "src/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "bin/main.exe",
                "-DDEBUG",
                "-I../lib/SFML/include",
                "-L../lib/SFML/lib",
                "-lmingw32",
                "-lstdc++",
                "-lsfml-graphics",
                "-lsfml-window",
                "-lsfml-system"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Copy_Assets",
            "command": "copy",
            "args": ["\"src/gfx/*.*\" \"bin/gfx/\""],
            "type": "shell"
        },
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "dependsOn": ["GCC_Debug", "Copy_Assets"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have install the SFML-2.6.0 (GCC 13.1.0 MinGW (SEH) - 64-bit) in ./lib/SFML

I have install minGW "MinGW-W64 GCC-8.1.0/x86_64-posix-seh" in ./mingw64

The issue seems not an error in include/librairy because in a gitbash shell it's work.

Tree of my project (I launch command from ./raytracing directory):

```
./lib/SFML
./mingw64
./raytracing/.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json
./raytracing/.vscode/launch.json
./raytracing/.vscode/settings.json
./raytracing/.vscode/tasks.json
./raytracing/bin/main.exe
./raytracing/src/main.cpp
```

If I launch this line on git bash, it's work :

```
../mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -g src/*.cpp -o bin/main.exe -DDEBUG -I../lib/SFML/include -L../lib/SFML/lib -lmingw32 -lstdc++ -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
$ echo $?
0
```

If I launch this line in powershell prompt, it isn't work :

```
PS D:\Users\Mathieu\Documents\Programmation\git\cpp\raytracing> ../mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -g src/*.cpp -o bin/main.exe -DDEBUG -I../lib/SFML/include -L../lib/SFML/lib -lmingw32 -lstdc++ -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
PS D:\Users\Mathieu\Documents\Programmation\git\cpp\raytracing> $LastExitCode
1
```

Comment: ***I have install minGW "MinGW-W64 GCC-8.1.0/x86_64-posix-seh" in ./mingw64*** Why do you have such an old version of MinGW instead of the recommended gcc-13.1 that VSCode tells you to install? [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: Normally when a compile fails your compiler is supposed to show you the errors. It's odd to me that it is not doing that.

Comment: I have test with le gcc-13.1 (in msys2) but I have the same issue

Comment: ***If I launch this line in powershell prompt, it isn't work :*** This is probably a problem with the `PATH` environment variable set in powershell. Meaning this path does not have the bin folder for your current MinGW in first or maybe not at all.